# Google Maps Api, How can I make the seach box to display results only for custom locations(for example locations that I want)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api. So far I understand how to make the basic map, how to add more than one marker on a custom location, and how to add the search box(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox). Whan I need now is that the seach results that are displayed are for custom locations only. In short, for example if I have 3 markers and they point at Berlin, London and Paris, and then I use the search box I must not be able to find any other locations except those 3. I was thinking about using an array with the coordinates of the locations that I want, but I cant make the seach box use this array as a data base to search and not the google database. Here is a site that uses this custom setting that I want: http://www.kebaben.no/, you can only find the locations that are marked on the map. In this site this is done by some database, but I like to do it with JavaScript and some array I just can't understand how to make the search box use this custom Array and search only for the locations that are in it. Thank you very much in advise.

Comment: Just something in addition, regarding the multimple markers I saw this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example

Comment: did you find an answer? If so, post it please